# Framer motion: do animation while transition occurs?

Tags: css, reactjs, framer-motion

I'm using simple transition effect for a toggle button, very similar to the docs, my Handle is like this:

```
    <Handle
      animate
      layout
      isOn={isOn}
      transition={spring}
      variantColor={variantColor}
      onClick={() => setIsOn(!isOn)}
    />
```

My Handle styling:

```
const Handle = styled(motion.div)<{ isOn: boolean; variantColor: string }>(
  ({ isOn, theme, variantColor }) => ({
    width: theme.spacing(3),
    height: theme.spacing(3),
    position: 'absolute',
    left: isOn ? '65%' : '0%',
    backgroundColor: variantColor,
    borderRadius: 'inherit',
    cursor: 'pointer',
  }),
);
```

The `left` propoerty transitions when clicking, so it toggles between '65%' to '0%'. What I would like to do is also add a scaling animation, one that makes the Handle larger and then going back to its original size, at the same time while the `left` transition takes effect. So if I try:

```
<Handle
  animate={{
    scale: [null, 1.2, 1],
    opacity: 1,
  }}
  layout
  isOn={isOn}
  transition={spring}
  variantColor={variantColor}
  onClick={() => setIsOn(!isOn)}
/>
```

The scaling animation occurs when the page loads, how can I have this animation trigger when transition occurs?
Please note that the scaling animation doesn't care whether `isOn` is true or false as opposed to the transition that moves the Handle from left to right and vice versa. The scaling animation is exactly the same and should just occurs alongside the `left` transition.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that one way to do it would be to use the `useAnimation` hook from framer motion library.

```
import { motion, useAnimation } from 'framer-motion';

const control = useAnimation();
```

Then use it inside onClick event:

```
      onClick={() => {
        setIsOn(!isOn);
        control.start({
          scale: [null, 1.1, 1],
          transition: { duration: 0.2 },
        });
      }}
```